# how can i validate the data in the control file?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Consider that the SQLLoader reads the Input data File from the path and it loads the data into the tables based up on the descrition specified in the control File.
First, the table to be filled is created:

```
create table sql_loader_1 ( load_time date, field_1 Numeric, field_2 varchar2(10)
```

Sample Control File :
load_1.ctl

```
load data 
infile 'load_1.dat' "str '\r\n'" 
insert into table sql_loader_1 
( 
 load_time sysdate, 
 field_2 position( 1:10),
 field_1 position(11:20)
)
```

Note that the positions 11 through 20 are loaded into field_1 and positions 1 through 10 into field_2. The field load_time is filled with the current time (sysdate) of the load.

Here's the data. The name of the file (load_1.dat) had been specified with the infile statement in the control file.

load_1.dat

```
0123456789abcdefghij
**********##########
foo         bar
here comes a very long line 
and the next is 
short
```

Here I want to validate the field_1 (Numeric Datatype)  since the data file contains the character value (i.e)abcdefghij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to validate field_1, but it's not clear what action are you expecting if the validation fails?

Two other thoughts:

1. Have you considered using the BADFILE option in your control file for rejected rows?
2. Instead of dealing with the number conversion in SQL-Loader, load the data as text and convert it to a number/handle it once in the database.  This may be easier.

Comment: I declared the field_1 as Numeric datatype but the input datafile contains the data "abcdefghij"(position 11 : 20) so the sql loader doesnt add the record to the database instead the record is written to the bad file.But i want to validate the data from the "(position 11 : 20) is numeric or not.How can i validate this in the control file itself? if it is not possible,how can i validate it in the database?give me a sample code to explain this.

Comment: But what action are you expecting if the validation fails?  The row to be rejected?  The whole import to fail?  I understand what you're trying to do, but you need to say what action to take if the validation is unsuccessful.